# does delay coroutine stop on when we background the app in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, delay, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using delay coroutine with 90secs delay. But after backgrounding the app for more than ~25-30sec, looks like it's getting stopped.
e.g.

```
// on a screen launch
var flag = false
delay(90000) // 90 sec delay
flag = true
```

As soon as screen is launched, I have backgrounded the app for more than ~25sec and when I foreground the app it is taking more than 90 sec (90 sec + background time) to set the flag to true.

So delay coroutine stops on background the app after a certain time?

Comment: What scope are you using?

Comment: What runs this code? Maybe it re-executes every time you go to foreground because it's run from a lifecycle callback that is triggered during that state change. It may also mean the app was killed in the background, so the `Application` init code is running again.

Comment: @HenryTwist I use viewModelScope, I feel like we should use module scope instead of viewModelSafe?